# How can I get all logged in Superset users?

Tags: python, apache-superset

Is it possible to get (in Python) a list of all the users who are currently logged in to Apache Superset?

Answer (score 1):

Apache Superset's default metadata store is a Postgres DB:

`SELECT * from  public.ab_user;`

The column "Last_login" will be useful for you; you can find the login count in this table as well.